# How to change date format in mysql stored procedure insert statement "22-12-2010" to "2010-12-22"

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, date

I send the registration date parameter to  mysql database like "22-12-2010". But my sql date date type is in another format how can I change the date format like "2010-12-22" also I have to insert this into table.

Give code in C#,asp.net code behind either sql query statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this comprehensive MSDN pages as your guide: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

There are many examples on those pages on how to reformat a date string in C#, and they also provide a good clear explanation on how date formatting works in the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28VS.71%29.aspx) class.

Once you've reformatted your date string in C#, you should be able to pass it on down without needing to use SQL to reformat it.